# regex - Checking for characters within 'line range'

Tags: regex

Im trying to search for characters within a string, but only within a range of the search string itself.

For example, lets say I have to look for the character 'o' in;

`the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog`

But, I only need to search for this character with the range of character 20 (the letter 'd') and character 25 (the letter 'r').

How would I write a regex expression to match just this character between both positions?

I have tried `^(.{20})o(.{13})$` to no avail. All I can find is resources about character ranges, ([A-Z] for example) instead of positional ranges

Comment: What language/tool do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex :

```
/^.{0,20}.*(o).*r/
```

In this regex, an anchor is placed at first `^` to make sure the match begin from the first character of the string, next we move from 0 to 20, precisely the end of letter `d` of jumped, then we use `.*` because we don't know how much space to reach the char `o` and another `.*` till we reach `r`,

demo https://regex101.com/r/PLHS43/1

There is another way using this regex:

```
/^.{0,20}.*(o).*?r{1}/
```

It basically does the same but it stops when it found the first `r` and match the `o` what is between char 20 and 25

demo: https://regex101.com/r/3cX2gw/1

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a compulsory search for a single regex? Unix prides itself on the passionate use of pipes to connect commands instead of writing complicated and therefore uncertain expressions.

in Shell

```
 echo 'the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog' | cut -c 20-25
```

or in Javascript:

```
 'the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog'.substr(19,6)
```

both will give a "d over" slice, and then a simple expression to find the letter "o" and make a section of what you want in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Designing an expression for the given problem is quite a puzzle, maybe we could just start with:

```
^.{0,21}\K((?:[^o]*)(o*)|(o*)(?:[^o]*)).{4}.*\K$
```

yet we'd encounter challenges, including the failure of `4` quantifier, when any `o` is being found.

My guess is that some sort of recursion might be required, difficult to integrate though.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZaWZe/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture a single o, you might use a capturing group:

```
^.{20}[^o]*(o)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.{20}` Match any character 20 times
- `[^o]*` Match 0+ times not `o`
- `(o)` Capture in group 1 matching `o`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h1ffET/1)

If you want to capture multiple times an `o` and [finite/infinite lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width) is supported you might use:

```
(?<=^.{20,24})o
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `^` Assert start of string
  - `.{20,24}` Match 20 - 24 times any character except a newline
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `o` Match `'`

For example a [regex demo in C#](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e.%7b20%2c24%7d%29o&i=the+quick+fox+jumpedootoooo+oooooooover+the+lazy+dog)

Answer (score 0):

This finds the letter "o" between the 20th and the 25th character in a string:

```
^.{20}[^o]{0,4}\Ko
```

**Explanation:

```
^               # beginning of line
  .{20}         # 20 any characters
  [^o]{0,4}     # 0 up to 4 any character that is not o
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this psition
  o             # the letter o
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WoGuDI/1)